# How to restart another agent in the pipeline which I want to use later

Tags: environment-variables, azure-pipelines, windows-services

I have two jobs in my pipeline job1 executed with agent A1 and Job2 with with A2. Both A1 and A2 running as service on the same machine. I will be change environment variable in Job1 and it needs to restart agent2. Restarting agents sometime askes credentials. So I need to provide credentials at the time of restart

So How can I restart a service? I tried PowerShell and batch file. Both failing to restart the service. Any help?

Here are few ways I tried:

1. With gwmi

```
$UserName = 'domain\username'
$Password = 'mypassword'
$ServiceName = "name='AgentName'"

$svc = gwmi win32_service -filter $ServiceName
Write-Host $svc.Name
$svc.StopService()
$svc.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$UserName,$Password,$null,$null,$null)
$result = $svc.StartService()
```

2. Batch file:

```
net stop "servicename"
sc.exe config "servicename" obj="domain\username" password="mypwd"
net start "servicename"
```

3. With Set-Service

```
$UserName = 'domain\user'
$Password = 'mypassword'
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($UserName,$Password)

$ServiceName = 'servicename'

Set-Service -Name $ServiceName -Status Stopped

Set-Service -Name $ServiceName -Credential $Credential

Set-Service -Name $ServiceName -Status Running
```

all options fail because of credentials. If I try from UI it works.
As I need to automate the process, want to run as part of pipeline.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why again do you need to restart the agent? You should *not* have to do that. Nor should you have to reconfigure the credentials.

Comment: When an agent is started, all environment variables and values will be set as capabilities of that agent. If we dont restart agent, we will not have modified environment variables and agent will try to use old values which will fail. So, we have to restart agent. When I tried manual process, it worked only after agent is restarted.... Also I read somewhere only restart will update the values to latest...

Comment: The fact that the agent's password seems to change from under it seems to be your real problem. You should not have to re-enter the password to restart the agent.

Comment: It feels more like a https://serverfault.com/ question to me. Relying on local environment variables on the agent is a bad idea anyway. can't you use pipeline variables or passing output variables between jobs instead? That way you can set the environment variable at the job level.

Comment: Unless of course you're installing new software on the agent using the agent, I'd recommend against that. You run into strange corner cases around requiring restarts and reboots because the agent relies on the tools being installed.